# ASP.NET Session_End: Determine source of event

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is there any chance to detect whether the **Session_End** method has been called after the session timed out by the timeout set in the web.config or whether the IIS itself called it after terminating the session due to the set Application Pool Timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***Global.asax***'s ***Session_End*** event.

***Session_End*** event is raised automatically when session expires or app pool recycles on a schedule.

```
private void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set 
    // to StateServer or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
}
```

Comment: ... and using the sender or eventargs parameter there is no chance to get the "actual" source?

Comment: What do you plan to do with sender and eventargs? I'm just curious.

Comment: Basically I have to run other logic inside this event handler, if the process got terminated by the AppPool Idle shutdown. (if it is even possible)

Comment: For app pool recycled or application unloaded due to Idling, you might want to use ***Application_End*** event.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very valuable hint.